# Why do the months start incrementing after the program begins a new month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I'm trying to build a weekly calendar for a set number of weeks. I start at the beginning date and loop through the weeks adding each day by the method

`nextDay.setDate( start.getDate() + num )`

which works fine until after the first day of the next month. Then instead of incrementing each day it increments each month.

```js
var content = $('.content');

function addZeros(int) {
  if (parseInt(int) < 10) {
    return "0" + int;
  } else {
    return int;
  }
}

var start = new Date("2017-12-01T00:00:00");
var nextDay = new Date(start);
var d = 0;
var dateStr = "";

for (var w = 1; w <= 8; w++) {

    dateStr += "week " + w + "<br>";

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        var factor = (d * 7),
            num = i + factor;

        nextDay.setDate( start.getDate() + num );

        dateStr += nextDay.getFullYear() + "-" + addZeros( nextDay.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + addZeros( nextDay.getDate() ) + "<br>";
        content.html(dateStr);
    }

    d++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.prototype.setDate` is not idempotent. Once you start giving it values in excess of the length of your Date's month, it calculates the new date based on your current month. Since you reuse the same Date object, every time you call `setDate` after 31, it jumps further than you want.

```
let date = new Date('2017-12-29T00:00:00');

date.setDate(30); // 2017-12-30
date.setDate(31); // 2017-12-31

date.setDate(32);
// 2018-01-01 (set date to 32 days after "currentMonth 0th": December 0th + 32 = January 1st)

date.setDate(33); // 2018-02-02 (January 0th + 33 = February 2nd)
date.setDate(34); // 2018-03-06 (February 0th + 34 = March 6th)
```

Instead of trying to explicitly set the date, let `nextDay` keep track of its own state. This line of code will advance `nextDay` by one day:

```
nextDay.setTime(nextDay.getTime() + 86400000); // 86400000 millis in a day
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use UTC milliseconds it's easier to do the math, because you can just add the number of milliseconds in a day and not worry how many days are in a month. Then convert it back to a date and you can use `.getMonth()` etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/z5vkfkLq/

```
var content = $('.content');

function addZeros(int) {
  if (parseInt(int) < 10) {
    return "0" + int;
  } else {
    return int;
  }
}

var start = new Date("2017-12-01T00:00:00");
var d = 0;
var dateStr = "";

for (var w = 1; w <= 8; w++) {

  dateStr += "week " + w + "<br>";

  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    var factor = (d * 7),
        num = i + factor;
        var nextDay = new Date(start.getTime() + 86400000*num);

    dateStr += nextDay.getFullYear() + "-" + addZeros( nextDay.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + addZeros( nextDay.getDate() ) + "<br>";
    content.html(dateStr);
    }

  d++;
}
```